# Android Single Quote In SQL With a LIKE StateMent

Tags: java, android, sql

I am having problem querying single quote while using the sql LIKE statement

this is my SQL query for searching the MUSIC file in the SD CARD.

```
final Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
final String[] cursor_cols = {
   MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE
};
where = MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " like ('%"+SomeSongTitle+"%')";
cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, cursor_cols, where, null, null);
```

`SomeSongTitle` is some arbitrary input text that the a user input.

My Question is why when `SomeSongTitle` contains a single Quote(for example `SomeSongTitle=don't`), it crashes.

And How to fix it?

thankz for reading and hope to hear some solution from you guys =D. hehe

Comment: thankz for all those who answer, there are many right answers. hehe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix it you need to replace the single quote with two single quotes. Try using something like...

```
SomeSongTitle = SomeSongTitle.replace("'", "''");
```

Comment: @xiaowoo: Glad to help. It's something I use a lot (TV Show titles in my case).

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to do String substitution you can use [SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) to get your Cursor object. And then do something like:

```
String query = "select * from your_table_name where" + MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " like ('%?%')";
cursor = yourDB.rawQuery(query, new String[] {SomeSongTitle});
```

That should get around the quoting issue.

Comment: +1 for a solution which also protects against SQL injections and means you won't lose sleep worrying about which other characters you need to escape.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to escape the *single quote*. There are much more sophisticated methods to do this, but an easy way to start is to simply to a find and replace in order to add a *slash (\)* before the *quote* mark so that it looks like this: *(\')*.

You can read more about it [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). ***Specifically, look at the section on Mitigation.***

Answer (score 1):

If you use bindings (?) for the argument(s) in the where clause, then you do not need and should not use any single quotes because the binding already takes care of that.
In particular, the second argument in a binding is an array of strings, 
String[], providing one String for each ?. In the binding process, each of those Strings is treated by sql as if it has single quotes around it. Binding creates a compiled sql statement with variable substitution, so it is efficient to write your sql as a fixed String and binding rather than make a different statement each call.

Answer (score 0):

Android's database API sits on top of [sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org). In its FAQ, you can see that to "escape" a single quote, you just use two single quotes. See [here](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q14).