# Single quote (') in edittext makes my program crash

Tags: android, android-edittext, quote

If I write something into an `edittext` that contains single quote (`'`) my program crashes. With this `edittext` I can search for things in my database and some of them contain this single qoute (or *apostrophe* whatever name it has but the point is that it's about the single qoute). I assume it has some special functions and this is why it crashes. Is there any option to ignore its function or solve this problem somehow?

for example, an item in my database:

```
cv.put(KEY_NAME, "Jonh's idea");
cv.put(KEY_HOTNESS, "amazing");
cv.put(KEY_MONEY, "500");
ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
```

Then when I search for it with this method:

```
return ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {"_id", "idea_name",},  
"idea_name like " + "'%" + qq + "%'", null, null, null, null);
```

where qq is given by the user (for example Jonh's idea), it crahses. And yes, I get syntax error.

Comment: Can you show some of your work? Is this `'` in your XML file, or in your code? Can you show the part of the XML or code that adds that character to the field? Also, what have you tried to fix the issue?

Comment: Try: `return ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {"_id", "idea_name"},  
"idea_name like '%?%'", new String[] { qq }, null, null, null);`

Comment: If that doesn't work then try getting rid of the `'`s around the `%`s

Comment: And if that doesn't work, just try doing `qq = qq.replace("'", "''");` See this post for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6146365/android-single-quote-in-sql-with-a-like-statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `selectionArgs` argument to escape the string (so that the single quote in it doesn't break the SQL). Try something like this:

```
return ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {"_id", "idea_name",}, "idea_name like ?", new String[] { "%" + qq + "%" }, null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like the `'` is causing an SQL injection of some sort... the `'` is causing a syntax error in your SQL statement. There are several things you might consider double checking:

1. `rawQuery()` will not protect you from SQL injections, so avoid using it (rather, use the `query`, `insert`, `update`, and `delete` methods instead).
2. Prefer formatting your `selection` and `selectionArgs` as follows (as it will protect you from SQL injections):

   ```
   selection = "col_1 = ?";
   selectionArgs = new String[] { "value_1" };
   ```

   (note that the values in the `String[]` replace the `?`s in the `selection` string).
3. Set an [`inputType`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType) on your `EditText` to prevent users from entering these characters in the first place (i.e. if you only want users to enter numbers, then set `android:inputType="number"`).
4. Overall, as long as you correctly make use of the Android methods in the `SQLiteDatabase` class, you shouldn't run into any problems with SQL injections (Android does a good job at cleaning this up for you). That said, if you don't choose to make use of these special-purpose methods, then you should check the content of the String at runtime and protect against characters such as `'`, `;`, `"`, etc. by escaping them.

You can refer to this post for more information:

[Android Single Quote In SQL With a LIKE StateMent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6146365/android-single-quote-in-sql-with-a-like-statement)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like  [SQL-injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). U have to escape your input.

Answer (score 0):

One more jugaad. You can replace ' with `. You won't have to recheck your code. Just modify the following:

```
String input = edittext.getText().toString();

if(input.contains("'"))
{
   input = input.replace("'", "`");
}
//now proceed with the database operation ...
```

This will enable the user to input text like ***RD's jugaad*** to ***RD`s jugaad***